# WMIC on multiple remote PC's failing with: Failed to open Node-list file

Tags: windows, windows-10, wmi, wmic

`wmic /node:@PC-list.txt os get csname,installdate`

Command above yields this error:

> Failed to open Node-list file (Please check the filename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the filename resolved:
`wmic /node:@"PC-list.txt" os get csname,installdate`

wmic doesn't like dashes/hyphens, I'd cite a Microsoft article on it, but I couldn't quickly find one detailing this. Error when hostname has a dash: *Invalid Global Switch.*

Comment: The same problem seems to happen with hostnames too.  The fix is the same, e.g. change `/node:my-server` with `/node:"my-server"`